# Conditional results by sex in R

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements

I want to calculate BMI as zscore in R using the SITAR package that weights it for age and sex.

To do so, I have split my dataset by sex and used this line of code that works perfectly:

```
dataset_males$BMI_zscore<- with(dataset_males, LMS2z(age, BMI, sex = 'm', measure= 'bmi', ref='uk90', toz= TRUE, LMStable=FALSE))
```

```
dataset_females$BMI_zscore<- with(dataset_females, LMS2z(age, BMI, sex = 'f', measure= 'bmi', ref='uk90', toz= TRUE, LMStable=FALSE))
```

I then merged them back together in a single dataset.

I was wondering however if there is a way to calculate the BMI for males and females without splitting my sample.

I am trying to combine DPLYR and SITAR as below with no success:

```
Dataset %>% mutate (BMI_zscore = case when (sex=='Male' ~ with(dataset, LMS2z(age, BMI, sex = 'm', measure= 'bmi', ref='uk90', toz= TRUE, LMStable=FALSE)), sex =='Female' ~ with(dataset, LMS2z(age, BMI, sex = 'f', measure= 'bmi', ref='uk90', toz= TRUE, LMStable=FALSE)), TRUE ~ na))
```

Do you know how I can achieve this?

Many thanks

Comment: Could you please provide some sample data to make the question reproducible? Paste into the question the output of `dput(Dataset)` or `dput(head(Dataset, n))` where n is a number that allows a meaningful set of data in order to verify a solution.

Comment: Are you trying to get average BMI for each gender?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dataset %>% 
  mutate(BMI_zscore = LMS2z(age, BMI, sex = switch(sex, "Male" = "m", "Female" = "f"), measure = 'bmi', ref = 'uk90', toz = TRUE, LMStable = FALSE)
```

If I understand well, this should work